# How to select 2.4G band in a dual band network

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager

We have an ASUS RT-N66U "dual band" router. This means it is capable of 2.4G and 5G simultaneously.

It is currently configured to make one network with both bands. For instance, everyone in the house is logged into "Milvia" network, but some of them are on 2.4G and some are on 5G.

For some reason, my ubuntu machine always selects 5G even when I tell it to prefer 2.4G. I'm trying to figure out why that is and how I can force it to use 2.4G, because I get poor reception with the current settings.

I have tried to configure it to use 2.4G band, by changing network type to "ad hoc", like so

[image: desired setting]

However, when I try to change this and reconnect to the network, it fails, and makes a new "copy" of the network with the default settings, which it connects to, on the 5G band. These are the default settings it generates:

[image: milvia 1 default]

I then try changing the settings to what I want them to be -- client mode doesn't let me select 2.4 Ghz.

[image: milvia 1 changes]

Again, when I try to rejoin the network it fails and makes me type my password again, and generates a new instance of Milvia network with the default settings, so that it ignores my changes.

[image: milvia 2 network]

[image: milvia 2 network settings]

When it does this I always end up with the 5G band, and as a result can't get reception in most places in the house.

Why is it fighting me like this and ignoring my requested changes?

**What can I do to make it select the 2.4G band?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do one of two things...

1. Fully identify the 2.4ghz network by use of the BSSID.
2. Set different wireless names for 2.4 GHz vs. 5 GHz.

Like so...

- Delete all WiFi profiles for Milvia, Milvia 1, Milvia 2, etc.
- Connect to Milvia and let it create a new WiFi profile.
- Edit the profile and set the BSSID of the 2.4ghz network.

Or...

- Set the router to use different names for the 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz networks.
- Connect to the desired network by using the correct name.

Comment: I ended up reconfiguring the router, it seems to work great now. Thank you!